# Get the 5 top of this query in laravel (take or first)?

Tags: php, database, laravel, inner-join

I have this query and i want to return the 5 top results in laravel but the take() and first() dont work at all it works only with get().The result are for each $id

**The query**

```
$user_lessons = DB::table('Home_LogStudents')
        ->join('LessonUnitSections','LessonUnitSections.leuns_ID','=','Home_LogStudents.LogSt_sectionID')
        ->join('LessonUnits','LessonUnits.leun_ID','=','LessonUnitSections.leuns_ID')
        ->join('Lessons','Lessons.less_ID','=','LessonUnits.leun_ID')
        ->where('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_action',101)
        ->where('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_studid',$id)
        ->orderBy('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_date','desc')
        ->get();
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach($user_lessons as $ul)
                {{ $user_lessons->less_Title  }}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions im doing this wrong ?

Comment: add `->limit(5)` to your query

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$less_Title

Comment: if you use `->take(5)` you still have to end your query with `->get();`. Have you tried this ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object :S

Comment: my code and the blade is correct ?

Comment: it worked...both i dont know which one to use....

Comment: what worked ? using both take & get ? this is the way you should do it

Comment: yes but limit(5) worked too with get both post someone the answer to close this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could either add `->limit(5)` to your query, either use `->take(5)` you still have to end your query with `->get();`.